# Mention Active Drive Folder / Current Drive Folder in the apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is the apps script which I am using for collating the data from different spreadsheets available in the particular drive folder.

```
function countValue() {

var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("foldername").next();
var contents = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
var file;
var filename;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var newname;
var status;
sheet.clear();
sheet.appendRow(["Folder Name", "File Name", "Sheet Name", "Status"]);

newname = folder.getName();

while(contents.hasNext()) {
file = contents.next();
filename = file.getName();

var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
var shts=ss.getSheets();
for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++){
var sheetname = shts[i].getName();
status = {1:shts[i].getRange('A1').getValue(),2:shts[i].getRange('A2').getValue(),3:shts[i].getRange('A3').getValue(),4:shts[i].getRange('A4').getValue()};

data = [newname, filename, sheetname, status]
sheet.appendRow(data);

}}
};
```

I am trying to use the same apps script for other drive folders as well. It is not possible to change the foldername each and every time in the apps script because, I have many drive folders. Is there any possible way to run the apps script based on the active folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a configuration Sheet where you store the source folder and destination sheet names as you like. Then in script, read that sheet and dynamically work on the folders and sheets.